# NSArray and NSDictionary add duplicate objects

Tags: nsarray, nsdictionary, tableview

When adding objects to NSArray or NSDictionary, my app only shows a duplicate of the last entry.

I get the data and send it to the observer...

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"xmlFinishedLoading" object:self userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:currentEventObject forKey:@"notifKey"]];
```

This code is ran when observer receives notification...

```
     -(void)populateCurrentEventsTableView:(NSDictionary *)events
    {

     NSDictionary *info = [events valueForKey:@"userInfo"];
     Event *evt = [info valueForKey:@"notifKey"];
     if (self.eventDictionary == nil) {
     self.eventDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

     }
    [self.eventList addObject:evt];
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[eventList count] - 1];
    [self.eventDictionary setValue:evt forKey:key];

    NSLog(@"events description = %@",evt.eventDescription);
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
```

TableView reloaded with this code...

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:       (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ActivitiesList";



UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

NSString *rowKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",row];

Event *evt = [eventDictionary objectForKey:rowKey];

cell.textLabel.text = evt.eventDescription;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = evt.eventSecondaryDescription;
return cell;
```

}

The NSLog that displays event description is fine it shows different entries as they come. However if I were to display the entries of eventDictionary, it shows same entry.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

More containing code would be helpful, what you've got looks good to me.  What method does this code appear in?  Is it possible that self.eventDictionary is being erased each time you come back with a `userInfo` object to populate it with?

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows same entry"?  is eventDictionary only 1 item long or is it the correct number of items (the number of items you've tried to add to it), but each of the n items are all the same?